# Is this "app" malicious or is it a bug?

Tags: battery, malware, oneplus-6

I was examining my battery usage and noticed this:

[image]

I don't know what this "-5" app is supposed to be. Could it be malicious or is it just a bug?

I own an OnePlus 6 with Android 10 (OxygenOS 10.3.5).

Comment: It is a bug (don't know if it is reported but a UI bug for sure, because it confuses the hell out of everyone for no good reason). We have had similar questions earlier. You can find them and see if the answers there help you out. https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery+unknown

Comment: Neither, it's a placeholder for an app you've uninstalled.